# How to get data from (bluetooth) serial port into python program?

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial-port

I have managed to receive data from a bluetooth connected device by implementing exactly this solution:

https://scribles.net/setting-up-bluetooth-serial-port-profile-on-raspberry-pi-using-d-bus-api/

This works fine using the minicom, but I need to manipulate the data which arrives in a python program. How on earth do I go about getting the data into a python program instead of receiving it in the minicom???

Also: as I am an absolute beginner with python, bluetooth and github this is the only solution that I was able to get working. I have tried several approaches over the last couple of weeks and I am sure that there are many other which are better and easier and I would appreciate any suggestions of better/easier solutions.

Python 3.7
RPi3 (1.3)

Connection status in bluetoothclt->info:

```
Device 00:07:80:E0:A4:FC (public)
    Name: WT11i-A
    Alias: WT11i-A
    Class: 0x00001f00
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no 
    UUID: Serial Port (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v0047pF000d0400
```

`sudo rfcomm -a show hci0:`

```
rfcomm0: B8:27:EB:A6:D7:4F -> 00:07:80:E0:A4:FC channel 1 connected [reuse-dlc release-on-hup tty-attached]
```

Comment: @ukBaz thanx 4ur answer, but after weeks of struggling I have a working connection sending the data which is being received by minicom. The prereq's for Bluedot are a Raspi and a 2nd Raspi or an Android phone, right? In my case I have a Raspi and a (dumb?) BT device (a scale) which sends data when I push a physical button on it. Thus, it feels as if I am close, but trying with Bluedot would be starting all over again. Since I have read many of your posts here on SO I know that you are a real experts, so I really value your input.

Comment: @ukBaz Most grateful for your answer. Why is the BT device the SPP client? Could it not be that the BT device is the server and the RPi the client? What in the solution I implemented ( https://scribles.net/setting-up-bluetooth-serial-port-profile-on-raspberry-pi-using-d-bus-api/ ) says that the BT device is the SPP client? Sorry for being such a brick, but I am so utterly totally lost after weeks of just trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: @ukBaz thank you for this clarification (=dispersing some of the fog) and yes your understanding is correct. Since I am able to do the connecting with Blueman I will try to build a Bluedot server app listening on the serial port for the data being sent from the BT-device. I surely will have questions so ... I'll be bäck!

Comment: Let's start again as I had got it around the wrong way. If your BT device is advertising then you need to create a Bluedot [client](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothclient) and put the address of your BT device as the `server` value. Before you can connect with Bluedot you will need to `pair` the RPi and your BT device. Pairing is one-off operation and is best down with `bluetoothctl` on the RPi. You can follow the [instructions](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pairpipi.html) for `second raspberry pi`. You BT device is taking the role 1st RPi

Comment: @ukBaz Thank you for explaining! Since I have a working solution (as mentioned above) I assume that no more pairing and connecting is needed (I have edited my post adding the 'connection status' above).

Comment: @ukBaz When I ran the default code for the Bluedot client I get the following error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bluetoothtest17.py", line 9, in <module>
    c = BluetoothClient("00:07:80:E0:A4:FC", data_received)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bluedot/btcomm.py", line 567, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bluedot/btcomm.py", line 660, in connect'
    self._client_sock.connect((server_mac, self._port))
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy'

Comment: If you type `bluetoothctl devices` in a terminal, do you see the BT device you are trying to connect to?

Comment: @ukBaz yes ( Device 00:07:80:E0:A4:FC WT11i-A )

Comment: `rfcomm` etc have been [deprecated](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) so there should be no need to use them. They bypass the `bluetoothd` that is running on the system that `Bluedot` and `bluetoothctl` use to interact with the Bluetooth hardware on the RPi. This means the system can get into an unknown state. Is rfcomm showing the RPi and BT device as connected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240199/discussion-between-ukbaz-and-mortpiedra).

Answer (score 0):

With the amazing assistance of ukBaz I finally got it working.
The trick is: ditch RFCOMM ... not much of a surprise apparently.
I disconnected the RFCOMM connection and did not connect using the 'Blueman manager'. By instead just running the Bluedot default client script it worked!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).