# Python bluetooth - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, bluetooth

I successfully connect a device via bluetooth with the app '[Bluetooth Serial Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-serial-terminal/9wzdncrdfst8#activetab=pivot:overviewtab)' to a Win10 PC and I receive the data in the app as desired.

I have understood that pybluez is THE way to program python BT applications, but if that is wrong please let me know what is a better (=simpler) alternative.

So since I now instead wish to connect the BT device over a Python script I have installed pybluez and [copied](https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/) the following code:

```
hostMACAddress = '00:07:80:e0:a4:fc'
import bluetooth
port = 2
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress, port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    client, clientInfo = s.accept()
    while 1:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
            client.send(data) # Echo back to client
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

When I run it (Visual Studio as an admin) I get the error:
'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions'

I tried to by changing the port number (I tried a bunch from 0 to 60000), but always get 'The requested address is not valid in this context'.

Googling both of these messages result in a myriad of discussions which all end up with me going into a mental tailspin.

I know very little about python and nothing about sockets, ports and networks so please keep it basic.

I also tried the following

```
import bluetooth  
serverMACAddress = '00:07:80:e0:a4:fc' 
port = 2 
size = 1024 
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM) 
s.connect((serverMACAddress, port)) 
try:     
    while 1:         
        data = s.recv(size)         
        if data:
             print(data) 
except:
         print("Closing socket")
     s.close()
```

This code does not interrupt, but nothing happens when I press the send button on the BT device. To clarify: when I connect with the Bluetooth Serial App data is received in the app window when the send button is pressed on the BT device

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to connect to what. I suspect the `Bluetooth Serial Terminal App` is a *client* and it is connecting to a device that is a *server*. The Python you have written is a *server* so will not connect to a *server*. You may find the following article helpful: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/   On windows you need Python 3.9 or newer for the Bluetooth serial socket functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am astounded about what difficulty I have to explain myself so that it is understandable. I raised the same issue trying to connect with a Raspi in the past where you yourself helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293858/how-to-get-data-from-bluetooth-serial-port-into-python-program/70378932?noredirect=1#comment124408864_70378932 . I am trying to do exactly the same connection, but this time with a Win10 instead of a Raspi. Also, the article you quoted is exactly where I copied the code from. I will now try instead the client code in that article.

Comment: @UKBaz I tried the following `import bluetooth

serverMACAddress = '00:07:80:e0:a4:fc'
port = 2
size = 1024
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress, port))
try:
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(size)
        if data:
            print(data)
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    s.close()` The code does not interrupt, but nothing happens when I press the send button on the BT device. To clarify: when I connect with the `Bluetooth Serial App` data is received in the app window when the send button is pressed on the BT device

Comment: It would be more helpful if you updated your question rather than put code in the comments. You own the code at both ends of the Bluetooth link right? What is the mac address and port number of the server? I assume you have used those values? What is happening at the server end? Is there a connection being established? We know your server code works because it worked with the Bluetooth Serial App. You need to share debug informaton about what is not happening on the server when the Python client tries to connect.

Comment: @UKBaz I updated the code in the question itself as you proposed. No, I do not own the code at the 'other' end. It is a 'dumb' device where I push a button and the data is sent somehow. I only have control of the client side.

Comment: @ukBaz you asked 'What is the mac address and port number of the server?' In the Win10 device manager I find the MAC (which is the same shown for the port 'COM5'), but the 'port' I am using in the code I took from the example (and tried with '2' since '1' gave the error described above)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code found [here](https://www.robertprice.co.uk/robblog/programming_bluetooth_using_python-shtml/):

```
import bluetooth
print("looking for nearby devices...")
nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, flush_cache = True, duration = 20)
print("found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices))
for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    print(" %s - %s" % (addr, name))
    for services in bluetooth.find_service(address = addr):
        print(" Name: %s" % (services["name"]))
        print(" Description: %s" % (services["description"]))
        print(" Protocol: %s" % (services["protocol"]))
        print(" Provider: %s" % (services["provider"]))
        print(" Port: %s" % (services["port"]))
        print(" Service id: %s" % (services["service-id"]))
```

and it revealed to me that I was using the wrong port.
I changed the port and my second code above worked fine.